# Chrome Headless puppeteer too much CPU

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, cpu-usage, headless, puppeteer

I have a scraping algorithm in nodejs with puppeteer which scrapes 5 pages concurrently and when it finishes with one page it pulls the next url from a queue and open it in the same page. The CPU is always at 100%. How to make puppeteer use less cpu?

This process is running on a digitaloceans droplet with 4gb of RAM and 2 vCPUs.

I've launched the puppeteer instance with some args to try to make it lighter but nothing happened

```
 puppeteer.launch({
    args: ['--no-sandbox', "--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas","--disable-gpu"],
    headless: true,
  });
```

Are there any other args I can give to make it less CPU hungry?

I've also blocked images loading

```
await page.setRequestInterception(true);
page.on('request', request => {
  if (request.resourceType().toUpperCase() === 'IMAGE')
    request.abort();
  else
    request.continue();
});
```

Comment: This is the same issue I'm having right now, also on DigitalOcean. Did you find any trick to taking care of it?

Answer (score 35):

my default args, please test it and tell me if this run smoothly.
Please note that `--no-sandbox` isn't secure when navigate to vulnerable sites, but it's OK if you're testing your own sites or apps. So make sure, you're know what you're doing.

```
  const options = {
    args: [
      '--no-sandbox',
      '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
      '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
      '--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas',
      '--no-first-run',
      '--no-zygote',
      '--single-process',
      '--disable-gpu'
    ],
    headless: true
  }

  return await puppeteer.launch(options)
```

Comment: Does seem to help a LOT!  Thanks!

Comment: P.S. a list of available args and their meanings is at: https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: Thanks for this extensive list @drmrbrewer

Comment: Thanks, but isn't it dangerous to use `--no-sandbox`?

Comment: Anyone else have any more flags that they think will help?

Comment: Huge -1 due to security concerns (no sandbox, really?)

Comment: As stated that `--no-sandbox` isn't secure when you browse vulnerable sites.
If you're just testing your own website, and of course you surely know what you're doing, you can use this argument.

Comment: Why disabling GPU may help CPU usage? 

Answer (score 2):

There's a few factors that can play into this. First, check if the site(s) that you're visiting using a lot of CPU. Things like canvas and other scripts can easily chew through your CPU, especially when it comes to using canvas.

If you're using docker to do your deployment then make sure you use `dumb-init`. [There's a nice repo here that goes into *why* you'd use such a thing](https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init), but essentially the process ID that gets assigned in your docker image has some hiccups when it comes to handling termination:

```
EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["dumb-init", "--"]
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

This is something I've witnessed and fixed on [browserless.io](https://browserless.io/) as I use docker to handle deployments, CPU usage being one of them.

Comment: i am using docker with dumb init, however it still chews up 50% of all 4 cores. no canvas used, only 1 page opened.

Comment: @LaurynasMališauskas do you have your dockerfile someplace public?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid parallel execution which causes high CPU usage , i had to execute jobs sequentially using

**p-iteration** NPM package. In my case it's not a problem because my jobs don't take too much time.

You can use either **forEachSeries** or **mapSeries** function depending on you scenario.